# Where srt file will be exported in Windows OS? - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I use below scrolling dynamic query in order to see srt file in my system. But I am not sure this file is generating. I am using 10.2B version.

```
DEFINE QUERY qcust FOR customer   SCROLLING.
OPEN QUERY qcust FOR EACH customer WHERE comments CONTAINS "customer" 
                                   OR comments CONTAINS "C.O.D.".

 REPEAT:
  GET NEXT qcust.
    IF NOT AVAILABLE customer THEN LEAVE.
      DISPLAY customer EXCEPT comments WITH FRAME q-frame 13000 DOWN.
 END.
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? : https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P111424

Comment: @Luuk- Couldnt understand. Can you pls explain in short?

Comment: Sorry, that would mean I have to read it.....    Currently it is unclear WHY you need to know if a sort file is created, and if it is created where it is created.

Comment: @Luuk- Since you share the doc then you must know the answer for question..Why dont you explain pls?

Comment: @Luuk - Everything is knowledge. I just want to learn and see what's written in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244741/discussion-between-bharat-and-luuk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nwahmaet states - the srt files will be created in the folder specified by -T or the working directory. The files may be hidden. As you can see the dir command does not show the srt files. The attrib command does. Alternatively dir /ah does show hidden files too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike..Now I can see the old srt files under the work directory. My above query should created srt file with file size 0..and the size is same even after I executed the query

Comment: Windows does not consistently update file sizes. It is normal for many utilities to show a size of zero until the file is closed.

Comment: @TomBascom My query is completed but still the file size is zero. I closed the session as well but this time the file is disappeared. I am not sure why I dont see data in srt file for above query

Comment: The real question is: why do you care? You only have to care about OpenEdge's temp-files when OpenEdge crashes and does not clean up

Comment: There is a program in prod in exporting audit data from audit tables. The perf of the program is very poor as it is running 4 hrs just to export 5GB data. Once a client connecting client-server succeeded then client session runs a query which requires a results-list srt temp-file on the server-side. Now the question is Will this srt file data is unique for the same query? If yes then can we do something to use this srt file directly to generate the data? so that we can avoid srt file generating each time which will save us some time.

Comment: The srt file is generated on the client. Not the DB server. And you should not rely on the contents of that file. It just contains the data required to sort the result set on the client and fetch records from the server in the correct order. 

When your report is time-critical execute it on the server using a shared-memory connection. An AppServer may help.

Comment: The SRT file is a symptom, not the problem. Your problem is that you have a query that takes at least 4 hours to run. That is what you should focus on fixing. Your time would be much better spent asking questions about how to make that query more efficient. Post a question about the query (along with the relevant table and index definitions) and you will very likely get some helpful suggestions on how to improve that query.

Answer (score 2):

It also goes into the temp-dir (specified by `-T` or the pwd if not specified)

Comment: Where do I check this path in my local machine? will it be there after I executed the query?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to be certain where the SRT file is being created is to embed something similar to the following in you procedure:

```
message session:temp-directory.
```